# How decision trees handle category type features when splitting nodes?

Tags: machine-learning

If the tree is a binary tree, it will consider all possible combinations of ways to divide the dataset into two subsets based on that categorical feature. Or it simply selects the features with the greatest information gain and splits them into subsets corresponding to each feature value. Which is right?

Considering a categorical feature with 3 unique values $a$, $b$, and $c$. Do we just try to split the data into 3 subsets $\text{Collection}_a$, $\text{Collection}_b$ and $\text{Collection}_c$ or we consider the possible combinations $\text{Collection}_{ab}$ vs $\text{Collection}_{c}$ and so on?